# Trying to implement the Facebook Wish List demo in Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, open-graph-beta

The [Wishlist](https://github.com/facebook/wishlist-mobile-sample) Facebook app example is supposed to demonstrate adding custom objects to the Facebook open graph. I have managed to get the application so that it runs and creates a Facebook object with a graph ID. The problem is I don't see any of the custom object information I enter on the Android end of the app appearing at the Open Graph node associated with the returned ID, nor do I see this information appearing anywhere else on the internet.

The Android end the app seems to encode the information into a URL which is then added to a bundle and put in an HTTP post. For example when I entered the product name "baseball" along with some image the bundled URL was:

https://evening-frost-8481.herokuapp.com/Server/product.php?og%3Atitle=baseball&image=4f038f901dc31.jpg

When I examine the resulting Facebook aggregation it contains a link to the url below (note: there is no explicit reference in my app to the extension /Server/product.php which suggests Facebook may be receiving some of the information sent from my Android app.)

http://eveningfrost8481.herokuapp.com/Server/product.phpcode=AQAcvYSQQhesHLoXFHF9NUK2m__2_ye722T8lTfCs_9EKlgWp-ngUKls-fUet7FXUG6Gv8pbEpDuSATVpdsHUE7FcD6TmU

Is there anyone out there who has successfully implemented this demo who can give me some over view of how the custom data is supposed to get to the internet and finally Facebook?